# using logic apps to move multiple excel attachments in an email to sftp

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I usually receive one excel file via email as an attachment. I created a logic apps to pick the attachment and stored it in sfpt. Now, I received multiple attachments in an email and my logic apps fail due to multiple attachments. The excel files attachments are named CRT06062018.xlsx, CRT07062018.xlsx, and CRT07062018.xlsx. 
Please, how can I create logic apps to move the attachments to sfpt.

Answer (score 0):

you can foreach with the attachments array that comes in dynamic content for mail action . 
then inside the foreach loop use your logic to store ea